# Android manifest package name

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

The package name we declare in AndroidManifest.xml is the unique ID of an application. To avoid naming conflict, we normally use domain name in this package name, like "com.google.***". If this is the case, there's no way to avoid other people using my domain name in their package name maliciously. Say if I am using "com.google.myapp", that's a totally valid package name even though I am not building apps for Google. Let's say my app has package name "com.mycompany.myapp", there's no way I can prevent other people using the same package name in there app.

Is this a problem that I should worry about? It seems this is the nature of Android, which can't be prevented.

Comment: I've added the 'java' tag to your question as this isn't specifically an Android issue. It's actually the way that Java packages are named.

Comment: There's no technical means of preventing this. A lawyer would have to tell you if there are legal means of preventing it, and most likely the answer would depend on your commitment (read: willingness to spend money).

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to prevent someone else from using an identical package name.

However the package name is combined with the certificate used to sign the package: if someone tries to install a maliciously named package on top of an existing package they will need to use the exact same cert. If they don't use the exact same cert then the OS will reject the install and the malicious package will not have access to the original package's data. In practice this deals with the security issues.

Comment: I think this is my concern, let's say I use the name "com.mycompany.myapp" in manifest, and I upload my app to the market. If there's already another app which has the same name, will the market reject my upload? If so, I will be forced to change my package name just because other people use my name. It seems there's no way to prevent this. Well, changing "com.mycompany.myapp" to "com.mycompany.mobile.myapp" is not really a big deal, but it's kinda awkward to have other people using my domain name in their package name.

Comment: Very true: I've never tried it, but I'm assuming that the Market will reject your app if you try to duplicate the package name.